# Update dataframe via for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below has to update `test_df dataframe`, which is currently filled with `NaN`s.

Each 'dig' (which is always an integer) value has corresponding 'top', 'bottom', 'left' and 'right' values, and the slices of dataframe, corresponding to respective top:bottom, left:right ranges for each 'dig', need to be updated with 'dig' values.

For example, if dig=9, top=2, botton=4, left=1 and right=5, all the `NaN`s within the range of 2:4, 1:5 need to be replaced with 9s.

The following code reports no errors, however, no NaNs are being updated.

```
for index, row in letters_df.iterrows():
    dig = str(row[0])
    top = int(height) - int(row[2])
    bottom = int(height) - int(row[4])
    left = int(row[1])
    right = int(row[3])
    test_df.iloc[top:bottom, left:right] = dig
```

test_df:

```
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    ...  633  634  635  636  637  638  639
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

letters_df:

```
   0    1    2    3    4  5  dig_unique_letters
0  T   36  364   51  388  0                   0
1  h   36  364   55  388  0                   1
2  i   57  364   71  388  0                   2
3  s   76  364   96  388  0                   3
4  i  109  364  112  388  0                   2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: As @yatu said, we would need to see how `letters_df` and `test_df` look like for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Aryerez, I've added heads of both dfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that in `letters_df` the value in column 4 is higher than the value in column 2. That means that when you do `top = int(height) - int(row[2])
    bottom = int(height) - int(row[4])` the value you will get in `top` will be bigger than the value you will get in `bottem`. So when you index `.iloc[top:bottom]` you have no rows in the slice. Maybe you should switch between `top` and `bottem`.